# How to use find command to find the directory of a filename and remove duplicates?

Tags: linux, unix, find

I'm using `find / -name "*.dbf"` to find the directories of all .dbf files.
It gives me the directories and the filenames.

The output should be only the directories with no duplicates. I don't need to see the filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe the result through `dirname` and then remove duplicates like this:

```
find / -name \*.dbf -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Thank you - I added 2>/dev/null to remove permission warnings `find / -name \*.dbf -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | sort | uniq `

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:  `find / -name "*.dbf"  -exec dirname {} \; 2> /dev/null | sort -u`

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your question in two ways:

1. To find only directories matching the `<name_pattern>` with no duplicates, you can use the `-type` option of the `find` piped into a `sort | uniq`:

   `find / -name '<name_pattern>' -type d | sort | uniq`
2. To find all the files, but only return the directories including the matching files with no duplicates:

   `find / -name '<name_pattern>' | perl -pe 's/(.*\/).*$/$1/' | sort | uniq`